# Пытаюсь сделать слайдер на js

Tags: javascript, slider

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь сделать слайдер на чистом js, суть такова. У меня есть массив с картинками, я нажимаю на кнопку и, очевидно, отображается следующая картинка. Я перебираю картинки через цикл for, но очевидно, цикл перебирает массив и выводит мне последнюю картинку. Как сделать, чтобы выводились картинки по очереди мне ума не хватает.`

```js
var array = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.png', '4.jpg'],
    section = document.getElementById('section'),
    next = document.getElementById('next'),
    back = document.getElementById('back');

for(var i=0; i < array.length; ++i ){
    next.addEventListener('click', function(){
        for(var i=0; i < array.length; ++i ){
            var number = array[i];
            section.innerHTML = "<img src='img/" + number + "'/>";
        }
    })
}
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно запоминать текущий отображаемый элемент скажем в кастомном атрибуте

Как-то так :

```js
var array = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.png', '4.jpg'],
  section = document.getElementById('section'),
  next = document.getElementById('next'),
  back = document.getElementById('back');


next.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var current = +section.getAttribute('data-current');
  current++;
  if (current >= array.length) {
    current = 0;
  }
  section.setAttribute('data-current', current);
  section.innerHTML = array[current];
});

back.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var current = +section.getAttribute('data-current');
  current--;
  if (current < 0) {
    current = array.length - 1;
  }
  section.setAttribute('data-current', current);
  section.innerHTML = array[current];
});
```

```html
<button id="back">back</button>
<button id="next">next</button>
<br />
<div id="section" data-current="0">1.jpg</div>
```